# UserEmailAddressException while login in Liferay

Tags: liferay

I'm trying to log-in in the login page of Liferay but It's showing UserEmailAddressException while calling authenticateByEmailAddress method in LoginUtil class of **portal-Impl.jar**.

I'm also getting the following warning.

No Group exists with the key {companyId=10113, classNameId=10039, classPK=10116} liferay

Here classPk is UserId but everytime it's taking the same value of classPk i.e 10116 instead It should take the logged in person's UserId from USER_ table.

I tried to find the implementation(code) of authenticateByEmailAddress method in **portal-Impl.jar** but couldn't find it. I failed to find how it's getting classPk=10116 that's where problem lies.

`String authResult = UserLocalServiceUtil.authenticateByEmailAddress(company.getCompanyId(), login, password, headerMap, parameterMap);`

When all the valid parameters are passed in authenticateByEmailAddress method. It should return 1. i.e successful authentication but UserEmailAddressException exception is being thrown.

Comment: Please check, looks like similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570204/useremailaddressexception-when-calling-login-function-in-liferay

Comment: On top of what @JaypalSodha says: Which version are you referring to? Is this your custom code?

Comment: Liferay version is 5.2.3. It is not my custom code. It is in portal-Impl.jar of Liferay

Comment: If there's no custom code involved, I'd suggest to rather ask this question on the Liferay forums, and honor Stackoverflow's focus on software development questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. It seems to be an issue in your installation and not a development problem.

Comment: did you change your email rules? did you mess up with the DB?

Answer (score 0):

"No Group exists with the key" error will occur when there is no corresponding  entry in the group_ table .
in Latest versions of liferay, after successful login, an entry will created in the group_ table. 
in this case, it may be corrupted/deleted. please check that way.

Thanks